# Retreiving a deployment from Wildfly using Docker and Uploading into Nexus

Tags: docker, wildfly, nexus

I would like to know if it's possible to create a docker image that installes a deployment from Wildfly server and then it uploads it to Nexus.

Is this possible? if so, what would be the recommended approach or are there any small exmaples online for this workaround task?

Any guidance or exmaples would be greatly appreciated.